# C# dynamic type comparisons cause exception NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

In the code below an exception is thrown when performing a comparison on the dynamic type.  Note I have enable breaking for all exceptions in VS2010 (Under Debug->Exceptions). The exception that is firing is "System.NotSupportedException" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  If I continue after this exception or turn it off the code runs correctly.

1)  Are not all exceptions bad and should be addressed (Not Ignored)?

2)  Does everyone else turn on all exception breaking in Visual Studio?

3)  In the "MyMethod(0)" case "value" resolves to int at runtime.  I believe it is fine to compare "value" against null even though int is not a reference type.  Is it because value is still really dynamic type underneath (Very similar to object) which is ref type.  Therefore dynamics would have all the abilities of their runtime evaluated type (ie value++) in addition to the features of type dynamic (ie. null comparison).

```
MyMethod(0); // Causes problems (value runtime type is int)
MyMethod(null); // Causes problems (value runtime type is ref?)

public dynamic MyMethod(dynamic value)
{
  if (value != null) {...}// Throws NotSupportedExpception
  if (value != 0) {...} // Throws NotSupportedExpception
}
```

Comment: No repro.  Check your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

While I could not reproduce your problem, FWIW, `null` is a special value type not a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code or something similar and did not get an exception. I have

Is it possible that the exception comes from what you are not showing ({…}) ?

Comment: The problem seems to be my logging system Gilbraltar (Similar to NLog).  For some reason when this logging system is started it somehow indirectly cause any future dynamic statement comparisons to produce the NotSupportException exception (Very tricky).  I was only able to detect this indirect corrolation by trial an error after realizing others do not see the exception.  If I can find the underlying problem I will post again.